# How to capture a MultibodyPlant's geometry hierarchy in an output port's callback

Tags: drake

I have [a system](https://gist.github.com/gbiggs/ee8ea0fa9c958fe97c15aaa2c7416b33) consisting of a `MultibodyPlant` (and scene graph), which loads an iiwa manipulator from a URDF file, and a `LeafSystem` that is creating ROS TF messages corresponding to the geometry stored in the `MultibodyPlant`.

The `LeafSystem` has an input port that receives a graph query object, and an output port that produces ROS TF messages. The input port is connected to the scene graph's graph query port. The output port is connected elsewhere, which is not relevant to my problem.

The `LeafSystem`'s output port's value is calculated by [this callback](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-ros/blob/6b056267ef362eb8a164e827e9f9f701334ff5ef/drake_ros_tf2/src/scene_tf_system.cc#L65). It inspects the scene graph and creates a TF frame for every frame in the scene graph.

The problem I'm having is that the scene graph has no knowledge of the hierarchical relationship between bodies in the `MultibodyPlant`. This means that the TF messages produced contain a set of frames that are all rooted in the world frame. I would like to instead have them reflect the actual hierarchy of joints and links that is in the URDF. The `MultibodyPlant` has this information. What architecture or ports should I use to make the information available in my `LeafSystem`'s output port value-calculating callback?

Can the solution to this be generic to any system that contains geometry, or does it only make sense for a `MultibodyPlant`? (I may not be understanding systems correctly here - I'm relatively new to Drake.)

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. [`GetPoseInParent`](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-ros/blob/6b056267ef362eb8a164e827e9f9f701334ff5ef/drake_ros_tf2/src/scene_tf_system.cc#L90)
 would return the relative one. and scene graph  inspector can query [parent frame](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_scene_graph_inspector.html#aca30abcce190c0618f4b6e57f7f56658).

Comment: Also you could check [GetGeometries](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_scene_graph_inspector.html#a738cc250d0634756df0264d8e732fd97) .